# tf1.13 Estimator with MirroredStratgy multi-gpu training, split the batch or multi-batch?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using version 1.13 of `tensorflow`, I tried to use `tf.estimator` with `MirroredStratgy` to utilize multi-gpu(say 4 gpus). With `ds = ds.batch(64)`, am I sending `64` samples to each gpu or `64/4=16`samples to each gpu?

Comment: I noticed you deleted your [closed TF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845317/tensorflow-2-0-is-getting-harder-to-understand-for-senior-tf-developers-does-an). That's OK, in the sense that you are entitled to close questions you no longer need. However, it looks like you were getting some useful links/remarks in the comments; it can be worthwhile leaving it up for that reason. The only reason to delete might be to protect yourself from downvotes (which will pass once it is no longer current on Meta).

Comment: @halfer Though I would be happy if my question get upvotes, I don't care much about the vote. I ask to get my answer, off-topic or not, I am happy that the question got feedbacks. I thought I was closing it by deleting it, not sure how stack overflow works, I need to read a stack overflow manual.

Comment: @halfer And I have noticed that one of my other question asked months ago got 2 down votes today. I guess they don't have any place to downvote me but pick another innocent question. That's kinda funny, lol.

Comment: No, questions broadly should not be deleted from Stack Overflow after the author is happy with their answer. The _primary_ purpose of Stack Overflow is to collate a high-quality set of questions and answers, for the benefit of future readers. However, given that you were probably impacted by [the Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect), deletion was probably wise.

Comment: Although it is good that you don't let downvotes bother you, it is worth noting that if you get too many downvotes across several questions, you may be rate-limited or banned from asking new questions. This is an automated system to prevent very low quality questions from entering the site from accounts that have a track record of asking poor questions.

Comment: I can't comment on the reasons for the downvotes on another question - voting is anonymous by design here. If you get several from the same person then an automatic vote reversal system should kick in. However on just two questions, there is probably nothing you can do (as it does not demonstrate a pattern of behaviour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `MirroredStrategy` replicates global batch size across all GPUs, so in your case, you'll be sending 64 samples to each GPU. Mirrored strategy also has  `make_dataset_iterator` and `make_input_fn_iterator` methods, which allow to split global batch size

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out that MirroredStrategy actually *divides* up the *global batch size* for each gpu.

Hence with a global batch size of `64`, *each* GPU (assuming we're training with 4 GPUs) would receive `64/4=16` input examples per training step.

---

The [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#using_tfdistributestrategy_with_keras) on `Distributed training with TensorFlow` had this to say about the following methods of providing the training data and evaluation input
 (emphasis my own):

**Loading Data from a tf.data.Dataset**

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(([1.], [1.])).repeat(100).batch(10)
model.fit(dataset, epochs=2)
model.evaluate(dataset)
```

**Loading Data from Numpy Arrays**

```py
import numpy as np
inputs, targets = np.ones((100, 1)), np.ones((100, 1))
model.fit(inputs, targets, epochs=2, batch_size=10)
```

> In both cases (dataset or numpy), each batch of the given input is **divided** equally among the multiple replicas. For instance, if using MirroredStrategy with 2 GPUs, **each batch of size 10 will get divided among the 2 GPUs, with each receiving 5 input examples in each step**.